# Plot a bi variate pdf when 1000 random numbers are generated from a bivariate Normal distribution

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, normal-distribution

I need to plot a bi-variate Pdf by generating 1000 random variables from a given (`mu` and `sigma`) of bi-variate Normal distribution. I tried writing a code (Matlab), but there's some error in it. Can anyone please check it and help me correct it.

```
function [ ] = bivariatedn( mu,sigma)
  % Generating 1000 random variables
  R=mvnrnd(mu,sigma,1000);
  X=R(:,1);
  Y=R(:,2);
  % Define the grid for visualization
  [X,Y]=meshgrid(R(:,1),R(:,2));

  % Define the constant (To write pdf in a easy way)
  const = (1/sqrt(2*pi))^2;
  const = const/sqrt(det(sigma));
  temp = [X(:)-mu(1) Y(:)-mu(2)];

  pdf=zeros(length(X),1);

  d=zeros(length(X),1);
  d=diag(temp*inv(sigma)*temp');
  for i=1:length(X)
    pdf(i)= const*exp(-0.5*d(i));
  end
  % plot the result
  surfc(X, Y, pdf, 'LineStyle', 'none');
end
```

> Error using surfc (line 39)
>   The surface Z must contain more than one row or column

This is the error being shown. Can anyone look into this?

Comment: The problem is exactly what the error message says, the surface Z (the variable `pdf`) contains only one column, it must contain more than one row / column

Comment: @SardarUsama so should i remove the diag function which only returns the diagonal elements?